# Activerecord find with multiple condition and a many to many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to fix a small query.

I have this class:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :sections
 belongs_to :brand
end
```

And in my controller I have

```
def show
 @content = Content.find params[:id]
 @related_contents = Content.where('brand_id = ? OR sections_ids IN ? AND id != ?', @content.brand.id, @content.section_ids, @content.id)
end
```

I must find all the contents with the same brand OR with the same sections excluding from the selection the content I'm showing in the view...

But I'm receiving a `PG::SyntaxError` ERROR

```
SELECT "contents".* FROM "contents" WHERE (brand_id = 1 AND sections_ids IN 11 AND id != 15)  ORDER BY "contents"."published_at" DESC
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "11"
LINE 1: ...M "contents" WHERE (brand_id = 1 AND sections_ids IN 11 AND id ...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "contents".* FROM "contents" WHERE (brand_id = 1 AND sections_ids IN 11 AND id != 15)  ORDER BY "contents"."published_at" DESC
```

Comment: Include the full error

Comment: This IN clause assumes a list where sections_id should be. Your code is not creating such list.

Answer (score 0):

`'brand_id = ? OR`**section_ids**`IN ? AND id != ?'`

You have pluralized "section" in your query. I'm guessing it is not a column.

Comment: @RobertoPezzali could you post your schema? It's difficult to see what the issue is when I don't know what your models look like.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `IN` clause.

I believe it should be:

```
 @related_contents = Content.where('brand_id = ? OR sections_ids IN (?) AND id != ?', @content.brand.id, @content.section_ids, @content.id)
```

Note the parenthesis around the question mark after `IN`.